# electron build single exe file

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I'm trying to export electron project to a single `.exe` file, containing all images and other stuff. I used *electron-packager* or *electron-packager-interactive* but none of them were correct and still needed resources directory. and I wonder how electron base programs like `vs code` bundled everything and have only one executable file?

**EDIT:**
for future viewers,
as @connexo [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49821796/electron-build-single-exe-file?noredirect=1#comment86660610_49821796) ,for example by exploring `vs code` installation path, you could see that `resources` directory exists and making `asar` build is all you can do!

Comment: The executable file you are asking is an installer.

Comment: you are right.thanks! @connexo